# Location Permission Issues after adding them in manifest file

Tags: android, location-services

I am new to android. I was trying to get location details.
In the manifest file I have used the appropriate permission, (Access_Fine_Location).

Still when I run the app I get an error saying Client must have access Fine Location Permissions.

My Manifest File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="androidfactory.rageshkr.com.iamsafe" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat Logs :

```
06-21 23:24:50.969  13542-13542/? I/MainActivity﹕ Location Service Connected
06-21 23:24:50.975  13542-13542/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: androidfactory.rageshkr.com.iamsafe, PID: 13542
    java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.ni$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.nj.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.nk.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.nf$1.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.nf$1.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.nf.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at androidfactory.rageshkr.com.iamsafe.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:93)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.f(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.gJ(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.d(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.f(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.dU(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.g(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$b.hy(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` must be outside your `<application>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="androidfactory.rageshkr.com.iamsafe" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample of using the permissions,services,receiver,meta-data in side the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="packagename"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:name="packagename.MyAppilication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Wipro_pos" >
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.CaptureSignature"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.findfacts.wipropos.ShopProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Packagename.CustomProgressBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.UnsyncRegistrationDetailes"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.SettingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Packagename.VisitActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name="Packagename.reciever.NetworkReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="Packagename.reciever.DateChangedReceiver"
        android:label="DateChangedReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="Packagename.UploadOfflineDataService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
</application>
```